# Can't find out how to check what team a specific player is on

Tags: lua, roblox

I need to get this code to check what team the player is on in Roblox Studio - Lua:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(toucher)
    local touchplayer = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(toucher.Parent)
    if touchplayer then
        script.Parent.Parent.Door.DoorMove.Enabled = true
    end
end)
```

How can I resolve this problem,whenever I go to player.Team, it comes out as being nil.

Answer (score 0):

It was easy:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(toucher)
    local touchplayer = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(toucher.Parent)
    if touchplayer.TeamName == "Add team name here" then
        script.Parent.Parent.Door.DoorMove.Enabled = true
    end
end)
```